# What do the Mapping APIs providers mean by 'transaction' or 'request'?

Tags: google-maps, maps, leaflet, mapbox, geocode

I am developing a web app that is composed by :

- a server-side : a Web API using ASP.NET 5
- a client-side : a single page that contains a map in which are several pins (10.000 at least, gradually) that represent my client's POI

Here's my constraint :

The map will be integrated in the client's existing website, and since I will be using the [Mapbox API](http://www.mapbox.com) (with the *Leaflet* library), I need to request the Mapbox server the least possible (free account/very limited usage).

I see that a lot of providers talk about requests and transactions, but I don't know what it really is.

**Questions** :

- Can I load my map with 10.000 pins **freely** ? What is a transaction actually ?
- When I load a map ? Is it a transaction ?
- When I put 10 pins in the map, is it 1 transaction or 10 transactions ?

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox's unit is a "Map View", which is defined as

> A map view is four map tiles when using Mapbox Studio styles, or 15 smaller map tiles when using Mapbox Studio Classic or Mapbox Editor Classic. One Static API request also counts as one map view.

[^ this is from the pricing page](https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/)

Map tiles are the 'base' map - the styled streets, buildings, and other features that Mapbox provides as context for your data.

If you're adding markers or pins to your map on your side - adding them via Leaflet or some other method - those don't have any effect on transactions or pricing, since they don't need to be sent to Mapbox at all.

So for this use case: when you load a map, it's typically one map view, but if it's a very small map it could be less or if it's larger it could be more. Adding pins to the map doesn't affect transactions or cost.